# over web access how do I move files between folders

Tags: ubuntu-one

When connected to Ubuntu one via an internet browser, how do I move files between my different folders in Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to move the files between folders in Ubuntu One web interface, you can just Publish, Download or Delete them.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to move files between folders:

1/ open ubuntuone on PC and on U1 webpage

2/ on the U1 webpage, create the folder you want (eg "shared")

3/ open your U1 folder on your PC, and you should see the new folder (eg "shared")

4/ on your PC, copy file from your U1 folder to "shared" folder.

5/ on your U1 webpage, you should now see the copied files in your "shared" folder.